# How to deploy an asp.net core 2.2 in linux apache server with revese proxy

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

Hello I'm trying to deploy an asp.net core 2.2 app in a linux machine using apache server and reverse proxy but I'm having problems to see my web app. I see this:

[image]

I will show you all the configuration i've made

Following this microsoft tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I've configured first my Startup.cs code like this:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

And the launchSetting.json like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63992",
      "sslPort": 44365
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ElectransCloudServices": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I compiled my project and I move into my linux machine executing the command dotnet publish --configuration Release -o /var/www/ElectransCloudServices to deploy my project into the correct directory for the apache configration.

This part is the project configuration. Now I gonna show you my server configuration:

I've created a configuration file called electransapp.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ with the following script:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ElectransCloudServices
    ServerName localhost
    # ServerAlias *.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using the 8080 port.

Then I modified the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf with the following parameters:

```
<Directory /var/www/ElectransCloudServices>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ServerName localhost
```

And finally I run the command systemctl restart apache2

After doing all this I'm seeing the first image I showed you. I'm pretty sure that the error is in the apache configuration but I dont know what I'm doing wrong.
Any help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've run the command dotnet appname.dll in my /var/www directory and it's working fine. There is a way that I dont need to run this command??

Comment: The document you linked to has a section “Monitor the App” which explains this

Comment: It's true, I hadn't seen it. Thank you ! @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: In this document I don't understand want kind of user I have to create to execute the service. Do you know how to do that? @SamiKuhmonen